# Formal power series (multiplication, divison)

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Let be $F$ the generator function of the prime numbers and $G(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-2)^{k}x^{k}$, so

$$F=2+3x+5x^2+7x^3+ \dots \\
G=1-2x+4x^2-8x^3+ \dots$$

> a) What will be the first four elements of the multiplication of $FG$?

I could compute it easily I get $2-x+7x^2-7x^3$ (I wrote the elements into a charter and after the multiplication I get fast the results)

> b) What will be the first four elements of the division of $\frac{F}{G}$?

To get this result I tried to find the "formula" for this calculation like the following:

$$(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+ \dots)(c_0+c_1x+c_2x^3+c_3x^3+ \dots) = b_1+b_2x+b_3x^2+b_3x^3+ \dots$$

after that I get $c_0=\frac{b_0}{a_0}$, and it's getting always much more complicated.

So how can I compute the $b$ question with this combinatorical way of thinking, is there any other "fast" way to get the result?

Comment: How complicated does the calculation get?  It's only four linear equations to solve ...

Comment: Isn't $\frac{1}{G} = 1 + 2x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same spirit as Christian Blatter's answer, you could perform the long division taking, at least, one extra term for $F$ and $G$ using then $$F=2+3 x+5 x^2+7 x^3+11 x^4$$ $$G=1-2 x+4 x^2-8 x^3+16 x^4$$ which make $$\frac FG=2+7 x+11 x^2+17 x^3+25 x^4$$

Answer (score 1):

So we have to determine coeffficients $a_i$ $(0\leq i\leq 3)$ such that
$$(1-2x+4x^2-8x^3+?x^4)(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+?x^4)=2+3x+5x^2+7x^3+?x^4\ .$$
It is easily seen that the resulting system of equations is triangular. This means that we at once obtain $a_0=2$, then immediately $a_1=\ldots$, and so forth.